# window.print prints the dynamic code and NOT what is on the screen

Tags: javascript, php, browser, printing

I have a page which selects data from a database for a selected person within a selected month which is used to provide an employee with their current or historic earnings.

Up until the end of April you could hit the print button and it would print out the page as per what is on the screen (text only) in the correct layout minus the colours and boxes etc, this sufficed perfectly well.

Then in May for no apparent reason the information that was collected from the database still displayed but now also has the url printed out, this is also the case when you use the browser print function as shown in the 2nd image.

[image]

Comment: Post the links to the images instead. Someone will turn them to images for you.

Comment: Thanks Parchment, only I'm not too sure what you mean by post the links? can I upload the images to SO?

Comment: you need shared resource images via http...then we can edit your post and they are included.

Comment: Would this be any good? I have uploaded the image to the site in question http://slbdistribution.co.uk/Untitled-1.jpg

Comment: Is there anybody that can help with this issue please?